# EC2- Run jar on running EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance and i have a .jar that i already took (wget script command) from S3.
I want to run this .jar file, but not on start-up, just when i decide.

I'm using Java with "Eclipse Juno" with help from AWS SDK.

Running a user data script doesn't help me here.

Can some one help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is unix cronjobs, 
take a look at the cron job manual [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) and set it to run whenever you want.

also, you can install [WEBMIN](http://www.webmin.com/) on your system, it gives you a great server management including cronjobs and scheduled commands as you need via web interface

if you want to run something with java, just use

```
String[] command={"java","-jar","myfile.jar"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) for remote invocation of shell scripts it's basically SSH within Java.

And [here's](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html) a simple example.