# How to run a Jar in Amazon EC2?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am fairly new to Amazon. I have a Java file which reads GBs of crawled data and I am running this using **AWS ToolKit for Eclipse**. The disadvantage here is, I have to keep my machine running for weeks if I need to read the entire crawled data and that is not possible. Apart from that, I can't download GBs of data in to my local PC (Because it is reading data).

Is there any way that I can upload the Jar to Amazon, and Amazon run it without engaging with my computer? I have heard about web crawlers running in Amazon for weeks without downloading data into the developers machine, and without letting the developer to turn on his machine without shutting down for months.

The feature I am asking is just like "job flows" in Amazon Elastic Map-Reduce. You upload the code, it runs it inside. It doesn't matter whether you keep "your" machine turned on or not.

Comment: Yes, you can upload it and run it. This has been [discussed][1] [before][2]:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564305/ec2-run-jar-on-running-ec2-instance
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669862/problems-in-running-jar-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: @crnlx: No it is not. You have to keep the Console open in your machine for that purpose

Comment: You can cron it, can't you?

Comment: @crnlx: cron it means?

Comment: I mean, can't you add it to the crontab? Please see the link which is part of the top answer to the first question which I posted above.

Comment: @crnlx: That is for "timing" the job.

Comment: you can do the standard `nohup` linux command, followed by a `&>` which will keep the job running when you exit the session

Comment: @AlSweetman: Can you give me an Example please?

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess: Yes, you can run it once or any number of times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can run with the [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command for *nix

```
nohup java -jar myjar.jar 2>&1 >> logfile.log &
```

This will run your jar file, directing the output [stderr and stdout] to `logfile.log`.  The `&` is needed so that it runs in the background, freeing up the command line / shell/

!! EDIT !!

It's worth noting that the easiest way I've found for stopping the job once it's started is:

`ps -ef | grep java`

Returns `ec2-user 19082 19056 98 18:12 pts/0    00:00:11 java -jar myjar.jar`

Then `kill 19082`.

Note, you can `tail -f logfile.log` or other such derivatives [less, cat, head] to view the output from the jar.

**Answer to question/comment**

Hi. You can use `System.out.println()`, yes, and that'll end up in logfile.log. The command that indicates that is the `2&>1` which means "redirect stream 2 into stream 1". In unix speak that means redirect/pipe stderr into stdout. We then specify `>> logfile.log` which means "append output to logfile.log".  As System.out.println() writes to stdout it'll end up in logfile.log.

However, if you're app is set up to use Log4j/commons-logging then using `LOG.info("statement");` will end up in the configured 'log4j.properties' log file.  With this configuration the only statements that will end up in `logfile.log` will be those that are either System generated (errors, linux internal system messages) or anything that's written explicitly to the stdout (ie `System.out.println()`) statements;

Comment: Hello, how the code know that it need to put stuff into the Log File? In case of Java, `System.out.println()` writes to the log file?